# Como fechar o teclado?

Tags: android, android-layout

Quando passo para esse fragment com o teclado já aberto, ele continua aberto, oque estraga meu layout, como ocultar ele ou não abrir?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implemente o seguinte método:

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Quando quiser fechar o teclado é só usar:

```
hideSoftKeyboard();
```

Se o método for implementado num fragment em vez de

```
getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)
```

use

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)
```